# How to add new item in foreign key in Django like the admin panel?

Tags: jquery, django, forms, dynamic

There is a small `+` sign on the right of a dropdown list in Django Admin panel which lets me add a new item after a new window pops up. Afterwards it gets automatically selected. How can I do that to my form in Django? I am quite comfortable in using jQuery.

Comment: Lightbox or a fancybox would do the job since you are comfortable with jQuery.

Comment: Can I add new foreign key items and have them dynamically added to the partially filled up form without loading the page?

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you are handling a project where you have a model called Book and Author.  Book have ForeignKey to Author.

1. In Book create / update page, put the + button and on click of '+', Open Author creation form in fancybox.
2. After successfully creating author, redirect fancybox to a page which containing some javascript.  That js should call a function written in main page. window.parent.myFunction({{newauthorid}}, {{newauthorname}}) should work
3. In the js present in parent page, add the new option to dropdown.

Comment: Can I use Bootstrap modal instead of fancybox?

Comment: @MiniGunnR If you use bootstrap modal, you need to use ajax to submit the author create form.  Author create form validation may become a head ache.  If you figure out an easier way to implement this with modal, please let us also know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help: https://github.com/sontek-archive/django-tekextensions

"since the admin interface already has all the functionality implemented we can ... reuse their code instead of reinventing the wheel"